# Check if memory is on the Heap?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a class whose `constructor` takes the address of an object as a parameter.

```
MyClass(OtherClass * otherClass);
```

In the `Destructor` of this class I try to `delete` the instance of `OtherClass`.

```
~MyClass() {
    if(otherClass != nullptr) {
        delete otherClass;
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is when I call this `constructor` I call it with an element from the `stack` instead of from the `heap`, thus I call it as below:

```
MyClass myClass(&otherObject);
```

so when the `myClass` object goes out of scope I get an exception. How can I find out if my `OtherObject` variable was declared on the `stack` or the `heap`? Or in other words, how can I know if I can `delete` the object?

Comment: If you don't have any object ownership rules your code will be chaos and you're going to have problems like this. Typically passing in a pointer is "giving ownership" to that object. If you don't want that, you'll need to change that to a reference.

Comment: You should make it a clear part of your class contract whether or not it "takes ownership" of the supplied argument, and then have the code that creates the object responsible for specifying it correctly

Comment: Consider using `shared_ptr<OtherClass>` , although this means you can never have a "stack object" given to it. Which is a good thing in terms of safety

Comment: @M.M: of course you can have a `shared_ptr<OtherClass>` pointing to a stack (or member) object: just construct a `shared_ptr<OtherClass>` with a suitable deleter function! I'm not using this approach frequently enough to state with confidence how that would look like but I think `shared_ptr<OtherClass>(pointer, [](auto){})` would do.

Comment: @Asesh: while the question is a duplicate, I think all of the answers are pretty terrible! Of course, having provide an answer to this question I'm biased :-)

Comment: @DietmarKühl agree with you, voted your answer cause as it's useful :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there are system specific approaches which will probably be able to tell whether memory is from heap or from a stack, that actually doesn't really help: you may have got a pointer to a member of another object on the heap. The memory would be on the heap but you are still not responsible for deleting the object. Put differently: do *not* go down the path you are on!

The proper way to deal with the problem is to make the ownership semantics blatantly clear in the interface and go with that. There are essentially two directions you can take:

1. Your class can deliberately **not** take over responsibility for the pointer passed in the constructor! Instead, it is the responsibility of the user of your class to deal with these objects *and* to guarantee that they are valid while your objects exists. If you can get pointers to stack (or member) objects the user already has to guarantee the validity of these objects anyway and for other ways it may be entirely trivial for the *user* to deal with them, e.g., by managing them via a `std::unique_ptr<OtherClass>`.
2. Your class takes responsibility of **all** objects passed and it will `delete` all of them. It becomes the responsibility of the caller to *not* pass pointers to objects managed elsewhere, e.g., to objects on the stack or member objects.

There is sort of a hybrid approach where your class takes responsibility of objects some times but not always. However, the implementations of such an approach is really a combination of the two approaches above: you'd take a suitable smart pointer as constructor argument and it is the user's responsibility to make sure that the smart pointer is constructed appropriately by the user of your class. For example, your class could take a `std::shared_ptr<OtherClass>` for which the normal construction will `delete` the object. When the user wants to pass in a pointer to an otherwise owned object the `std::shared_ptr<OtherClass>` would be constructed with a deleter which does *not* `delete` the pointer. Here is a simple program demonstrating the two different management strategies for `std::shared_ptr`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct foo {
    char const* name;
    foo(char const* name)
        : name(name) {
        std::cout << "foo::foo(" << name << "): " << this << "\n";
    }
    ~foo() {
        std::cout << "foo::~foo(" << name << "): " << this << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<foo>(new foo("heap"));
    foo f("stack");
    std::shared_ptr<foo>(&f, [](auto){});
}
```

Comment: By system specific approaches you are probably referring to finding the value stack pointer (esp or rsp) and the bottom of stack (esp + offset). Then you compare the value and check if it falls with in the stack's range. But remember, your code is not going to be portable, if you do so.

Comment: @Asesh: yes, indeed: while I'm aware that on most systems you can [currently(*)] tell whether a pointer refers to the heap or the stack, I obviously recommend *not* to take advantage of this approach. (*) If/when [stackful] coroutines become available it would become harder to tell whether a pointer points to the heap or a stack as the coroutine stacks would come from the heap. However, that is just another reason for *not* taking advantage of location of an objects [for deciding whether it to be `delete`d or not].